# Why does Java not support type inference for constructors?

Tags: java, generics

E.G. to create an ArrayList of Strings we have to do something like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

whereas it should be able to infer the parameter type for the constructor so that we only have to type

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

Why can't the type be infered in the same way that type parameters are infered for generic methods.

Comment: Is there a purpose to asking "why can't language X do feature Y"?  The answer is usually "because it wasn't designed to".

Comment: Why! Oh Why! That's one of my biggest complains about the generics implementation in Java. Wrapping the constructor in a static factory method makes the type inference work like a charm, so why not with the constructor!

Comment: @skaffman: true, but the confusing thing is that type inference does exist for parameterized methods, so the rules and complexity of implementation already exist. Just not for object instanciation!

Comment: To me it seems much more natural (and safer) to infer type (including type parameterization) from the rvalue rather than the lvalue. If it weren't for only providing an interface on the field declaration, I'd be comfortable with `ArrayList<String> list = new();`.

Comment: @Cecil Has a Name: I don't see how you could do what except if ArrayList is final. It's almost the same with `List<String> x = new(); `. Which `List` implementation should be used?

Comment: @Robert: ArrayList is not abstract and that's all that matters, whereas List is not, but an interface. If the lvalue is not abstract, writing `new()` as the rvalue does not complicate reading, whereas `List<String> list = new ArrayList();` provides the type parameter on the lvalue, but the implementation on the rvalue, without the type parameter. I'm more comfortable with C#'s `var` keyword. If I remember correctly, there is an ungeneric/untyped ArrayList too, not complicating the inference much, but it seems a bit dubious.

Comment: @Cecil: as long as there ArrayList is not final the expression is ambiguous, since it's legal to write both `ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(); and `ArrayList<String> strings = new MyCustomArrayList();`, whereas `new ArrayList<>();` is clear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a Java 7 improvement also known as the diamond operator. The syntax will be:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

The official proposal, [accepted for inclusion in Project Coin](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five) is [Improved Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000009.html)

According to [Rémi Forax](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/forax/archive/2009/08/27/diamond-gate), the change is already in the mercurial repository.

Comment: While this is good to know, it doesn't answer the question why the current version *doesn't* support this.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I can't offer a definitive answer as to why, but by reading the bug reports referred by the Diamond proposal I can see that the solution was not well understood in the Java 5 timeframe. Heck, generics are a bit borked even without pushing constructor inference in Java 5.

Comment: @Joachim...I believe the phrase you're looking for is "design oversight".

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, this is [on the list for Java 7](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#typeinference). However, I'd like to point out that the [Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) already sort of supports this for various collections, if you're happy to use static imports. For instance, I frequently write code such as:

```
List<String> list = newArrayList();
```

All you need is the static import and remove the space between `new` and `ArrayList()` :)

(The static import would be to the [`Lists`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) class, btw. There are similar methods for maps etc.)

Comment: Personally I think that this is very ugly. :)

Comment: It's odd when you first see it, but when you're used to it it can significantly reduce clutter.

Comment: +1.  I use this without thinking these days, because Eclipse will insert the import when autocompleting, and I have Google Collections on my default build path.

Answer (score 2):

It can be and it's a feature slated for inclusion in [JDK7](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#typeinference).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from JDK7 features, I'm guessing so you can use *extends* and *super*.

```
class Animal {}
class  Dog extends Animal {}

List<? extends Animal> anims = new ArrayList<Dog>();
List<? super Dog> superdogs = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

You wouldn't be able to infer in these two cases.

Comment: Type inference would only be used if you didn't specify it manually (just as it is with typed methods right now), so it wouldn't make this impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You want a reason the current Java doesn't support it.

I can only say that Java typically takes little steps wherever possible.  I would guess that there was some little technical glitch that they weren't sure about getting "Right" before Java 7--probably something to do with being absolutely certain it wouldn't create an ambiguous case in some older or non-generic code.

Notice how Robert pointed out that the syntax will be this:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Notice the empty <>?  I'm guessing that's to disambiguate this type of inference from older non-generic code; it's probably just something they didn't think of at first.

Comment: Yeh, I've just read Robert's links and the <> is to disambiguate from raw types ass you say.

Comment: Interesting that this sort of the opposite direction taken in C# where the explicit type is on the right hand side and the the type of the variable instead is inferred. Note that in C#'s implementation that this also allows you to infer return types from other method calls without having to explicitly define the type.

var strings = new ArrayList<String>();

I have to add that at first I didn't so much care for the var keyword in C# but the more I get to use it and together with type inference of generics and anonymous types it all becomes very cohesive.

Answer (score 1):

The type can be inferred, but the authors just decided it is better not to have type inference at all then have some limited type inference in some cases.

If you want type inference on jvm, check out [scala](http://www.scala-lang.org).

Comment: The problem is that there is some type inference! Type parameters on parameterized methods are infered just fine! Why can't the same rules be applied to object creation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java super-expert, so I'm not completely sure about what I will state. Here are my thoughts:

As Java implements generics by erasure, for every generic type there is an underlying raw type. If you define a generic type, there will be an underlying raw type that will use `Object` all around.

When you instantiate a new `ArrayList`, it would be wrong for compiler to infer the type parameter from the instantiation class (`ArrayList<String>` in your example), as there is a class with that exact name and no type parameter (that is the raw type, `ArrayList`). I also guess that this is why in java 7 you will have to add `<>` to the constructor call to tell the compiler to infer the type.

One could argue that the compiler should instantiate the raw type only when the definition class is the raw type, but I think that it would be confusing. I think that the compiler have to infer from incomplete expressions that would be invalid with no given context, which is not the case for the `new ArrayList()` statement.

I hope this is clear, and that if I'm wrong someone can correct me.

---

Side note:

Also, beware that the raw class is not the same as the type using `Object` as type parameter:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

is valid, where as

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

is not. In the first case, the raw type can be used as if it was a generic type, but in the second case you ask for contravariance which is not available (not if you don't use wildcards).

Comment: I felt like answering this question because I think none of the answers (which are all excellent!) here really address the initial question that is *why* :)